# "InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token" when redirect to the callbackURL

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am learning passportjs and coding an oauth client in order do consume some api data from provider. I have coded like Scott (http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/07/02/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-oauth2-server/) and everything is working fine like in the tutorial.

But now, I want to build my client app; I've tried to use passport-oauth2 but with no success : https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2

When I get redirect to the callbackURL I got "InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token".

Provider is running in : localhost:3000
Client is running in : localhost:4000

Am I missing something? Could someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: did you solved the issue? I'm facing the same error with no clue on whats failing

Comment: hello @garnav. I've started coding again...no specific solution for that :( sorry

Comment: thanks for your answer @angellica.araujo, I managed to fix my issue, it was a trailling slash / in the end of the access token url that caused a redirect in the provider to the non-slash url and lost the POST data :D

Comment: thanks @garcianavalon! turns out my issue was resolved by fixing the tokenURL as well.